# Basic RewriteRule in htaccess does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to the htaccess world, and I've been trying to make a very simple redirect: localhost/profiletest should show localhost/profile.

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove ".php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]

# This is the rule that does not work:
RewriteRule ^/profiletest$ /profile.php

# 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The first rule (to remove ".php") works just fine.

But localhost/profiletest shows me the 404 page, not the profile page. What am I doing wrong here? (And is the ".php" in the profile rule necessary when I have the other rule above it?)

I have also tried simplifying my htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profiletest$ /profile.php

# 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

with the same result (/profiletest shows the 404 page).

Comment: When configured via .htaccess, the URL path RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much, that was my mistake!